# Disable windows 10 volume control

Tags: windows-10, audio

This has got to be the most annoying addition in Windows 10.

> [image]

Half the time it covers the back button in some browser or bookmark.

What's worse is when there's a fullscreen application running. This volume control doesn't render, but if you click in that general area it will MAX out your volume.

This has happened too many times to count.

Is there a way to disable this popup and reclaim the space that it takes up whenever volume is adjusted?

---

As an addendum to Windows 10 volume control, is there a way to disable increasing intervals when decrease the volume?

I'll explain.

If you have your volume at 50. Pressing volume down on your keyboard will decrease it in intervals of 2. So one press = 48, another press = 46.

But with quick taps (pressing the volume down multiple times), it starts changing intervals. It goes from 50 to 48 then all of a sudden it goes to 30 and 20. This hurts my ears way more than if it was just gradual. If there's a way to disable this too that would be amazing.

Comment: any luck getting rid of this super annoying incremental volume decrease rate?

Comment: If it wasn't clickable I would be okay with an occasional annoying useless feature such as this, but like you said it will max out your volume at times. Not only did this nearly destroy my amplifiers and eardrums, it almost got me evicted. Microsoft applications are so lousy.

Comment: Agree - 4 years later this is still an issue. I've just gotten used to not clicking anywhere near the top-left when adjusting my volume.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no functionality built into Windows 10 to disable it. However, an open source, free utility is available to disable it.

http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1#more-1

Comment: It would be good to include some excerpt from the reference as a quote to provide more context.